# Root geometry expand Python

Tags: python, background, tkinter, window

I was wondering if there is any way to expand a background color while expanding root window? I'm talking about that if I expand my root window with mouse or just click "Max" there appears a grey frame around my blue one. What should do to expand my color with root? Here is a part of my code:

```
class Program(Frame):

    def __init__(self, root):

        Frame.__init__(self, root)
        self.root = root       
        self.initUI()

    def initUI(self):

        self.root.title('OptoMaQ')
        Style().configure('TFrame', background = '#6666ff')
        Style().configure('TButton',background = '#6666ff')
```

But I'm not sure what to put in there to make it works properly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is likely that you're not putting the Program frame in the root window in such a way that it fills the window. What you are seeing is the root window that is behind the frame. You probably need to adjust the parameters where you grid, pack or place the program in the root window.

An easy way to see that is to do `self.root.configure(background="red")`, which will likely show you a big red border around your blue frame.

Comment: Thakns. It's so simple that I'm quite embarrased :)